# Merge Source Table Into Target Table using subjoins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQLDeveloper. Please help me in correcting the merge syntax.I want to merge the data from act_sl tavle into act_sls_0 table 
I am using 2 joins in From Clause. 
But I am Getting Errors : 
Error(13,13): PL/SQL: ORA-00969: missing ON keyword
Error(4,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

```
merge into act_sls_0 using(
( select * from 
(select a_0.asp, gadim.uic as ga, pmm_styleid, week, colorcode ,  sizecode,      storenum, units_asly,retail_asly,
        cost_asly ,units_asregly,retail_asregly,units_asmkdly,retail_asmkdly,units_as_pln,retail_as_pln
        from act_sls 
        join dimension w on w.externalkey   = 'W'||substr(WEEK,3,2)||'_'||substr(WEEK,5,2)
        join a_0 on ( w.externalkey between startweek and endweek)
        join dimension strdim on strdim.externalkey = (case when length(storenum) <= 4 then RPAD('STR-', 8 - length(storenum), '0') else 'STR-' END) || storenum
        join store_info_0 str on store = strdim.uic
        join dimension gadim on gadim.externalkey = decode(store_type, 'RETAIL', 'GA-01', 'ECOM', 'GA-02', '')
        where trendweeks < 6)t1
        join(select distinct asp, product, ga, color, sstyl_shade, pmm_styleid  from aplc_1 aplc
        join apc_1 apc using (asp,product,color)
        where activeitem = 1 and ga!=0 and color != 0)t2
        on  (t1.asp = t2.asp and 
        t1.pmm_styleid = t2.pmm_styleid
        and (case when length(t1.colorcode) <= 4 then RPAD('SHD-', 8 - length(t1.colorcode), '0') else 'SHD-' END) || t1.colorcode = t2.sstyl_shade
        and t1.ga = t2.ga))src
        on (trg.asp = src.asp and trg.pmm_styleid = src.pmm_styleid and     trg.colorcode = src.colorcode and trg.ga = src.ga) 
      when matched THEN 
 update SET 
when matched THEN 
update SET 
trg.UNITS_ASLY     = src.UNITS_ASLY,
trg.RETAIL_ASLY    = src.RETAIL_ASLY,
trg.COST_ASLY      = src.COST_ASLY,
trg.UNITS_ASREGLY  = src.UNITS_ASREGLY,
trg.RETAIL_ASREGLY = src.RETAIL_ASREGLY,
trg.UNITS_ASMKDLY  = src.UNITS_ASMKDLY,
trg.RETAIL_ASMKDLY = src.RETAIL_ASMKDLY,
trg.UNITS_AS_PLN   = src.UNITS_AS_PLN,
trg.RETAIL_AS_PLN  = src.RETAIL_AS_PLN
 when not matched then insert           
(trg.asp,trg.ga, trg.pmm_styleid,         trg.colorcode,trg.sizecode,trg.storenum,trg.week,trg.UNITS_ASLY,trg.RETAIL_ASLY ,trg.COST_ASLY ,    trg.UNITS_ASREGLY ,trg.RETAIL_ASREGLY ,
  trg.UNITS_ASMKDLY ,trg.RETAIL_ASMKDLY ,trg.UNITS_AS_PLN ,trg.RETAIL_AS_PLN )                                                  
values                                                  
  (src.asp,src.ga, src.pmm_styleid, src.colorcode,src.sizecode,src.storenum,src.week,src.UNITS_ASLY,src.RETAIL_ASLY,src.COST_ASLY,src.UNITS_ASREGLY,
   src.RETAIL_ASREGLY, src.UNITS_ASMKDLY, src.RETAIL_ASMKDLY, src.UNITS_AS_PLN, src.RETAIL_AS_PLN);
```

Comment: You appear to be missing your ON statement that joins your target (act_sls_0) and your source (the big subquery). It should go just before your WHEN MATCHED THEN.

Answer (score 0):

The format for a merge statement is:

```
merge into <target_table> tgt
  using <table_name or subquery> src
  on (<join conditions between the target and source datasets>)
when matched then
  update set ...
when not matched then 
  insert (...)
  values (...);
```

Quite apart from the fact that your source subquery is incorrect (there are errors around where the t1 and t2 are; too many brackets, inappropriately trying to alias something etc), whilst you have join conditions inside your subquery, you're completely missing the ON clause for the merge itself.

You need to define the join conditions that match the data returned by your source subquery to your target table.

Comment: Ok. Now I used On Clause to match. But Now I am Getting Error- Invalid Identifier - src.ga . But I have this column in the target table . merge into act_sls_0 trg using( select * from 
(select a_0.asp,    - - - - - - -  )t1
            join(-  - - - - - - -) t2
                    ON (       )     )src
            on (trg.asp = src.asp and trg.pmm_styleid = src.pmm_styleid and trg.colorcode = src.colorcode and trg.ga = src.ga)

Comment: can you update your question to include your amended merge statement, please? When I copy your current statement, it produces all sorts of syntax errors in the source subquery. Please make sure you correct them before uploading the statement. Please also bear in mind that we can't see your tables, so you should make sure all column references in the source subquery are aliased to the correct table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Now the error is : src.ga - Invalid Identifier
```

Although I have ga table in Trg table and src table .

```
merge into act_sls_0 trg using( select * from 
(select a_0.asp, gadim.uic as ga, pmm_styleid, week, colorcode ,  sizecode,      storenum, units_asly,retail_asly,
        cost_asly ,units_asregly,retail_asregly,units_asmkdly,retail_asmkdly,units_as_pln,retail_as_pln
        from act_sls 
        join dimension w on w.externalkey   = 'W'||substr(WEEK,3,2)||'_'||substr(WEEK,5,2)
        join a_0 on ( w.externalkey between startweek and endweek)
        join dimension strdim on strdim.externalkey = (case when length(storenum) <= 4 then RPAD('STR-', 8 - length(storenum), '0') else 'STR-' END) || storenum
        join store_info_0 str on store = strdim.uic
        join dimension gadim on gadim.externalkey = decode(store_type, 'RETAIL', 'GA-01', 'ECOM', 'GA-02', '')
        where trendweeks < 6)t1
        join(select distinct asp, product, ga, color, sstyl_shade, pmm_styleid  from aplc_1 aplc
        join apc_1 apc using (asp,product,color)
        where activeitem = 1 and ga!=0 and color != 0)t2
        on  (t1.asp = t2.asp and 
        t1.pmm_styleid = t2.pmm_styleid
        and (case when length(t1.colorcode) <= 4 then RPAD('SHD-', 8 - length(t1.colorcode), '0') else 'SHD-' END) || t1.colorcode = t2.sstyl_shade
        and t1.ga = t2.ga))src
        on (trg.asp = src.asp and trg.pmm_styleid = src.pmm_styleid and trg.colorcode = src.colorcode and trg.ga = src.ga)      
when matched THEN 
update SET 
trg.UNITS_ASLY     = src.UNITS_ASLY,
trg.RETAIL_ASLY    = src.RETAIL_ASLY,
trg.COST_ASLY      = src.COST_ASLY,
trg.UNITS_ASREGLY  = src.UNITS_ASREGLY,
trg.RETAIL_ASREGLY = src.RETAIL_ASREGLY,
trg.UNITS_ASMKDLY  = src.UNITS_ASMKDLY,
 trg.RETAIL_ASMKDLY = src.RETAIL_ASMKDLY,
trg.UNITS_AS_PLN   = src.UNITS_AS_PLN,
 trg.RETAIL_AS_PLN  = src.RETAIL_AS_PLN
 when not matched then insert           
 (trg.asp,trg.ga, trg.pmm_styleid,      trg.colorcode,trg.sizecode,trg.storenum,trg.week,trg.UNITS_ASLY,trg.RETAIL_ASLY ,trg.COST_ASLY ,trg.UNITS_ASREGLY ,trg.RETAIL_ASREGLY ,
  trg.UNITS_ASMKDLY ,trg.RETAIL_ASMKDLY ,trg.UNITS_AS_PLN ,trg.RETAIL_AS_PLN )                                                  
values                                                  
  (src.asp,src.ga, src.pmm_styleid, src.colorcode,src.sizecode,src.storenum,src.week,src.UNITS_ASLY,src.RETAIL_ASLY,src.COST_ASLY,src.UNITS_ASREGLY,
   src.RETAIL_ASREGLY, src.UNITS_ASMKDLY, src.RETAIL_ASMKDLY, src.UNITS_AS_PLN, src.RETAIL_AS_PLN);
```

commit;

Comment: TAble act_sls  has columns : PMM_STYLEID
COLORCODE
SIZECODE
STORENUM
WEEK
UNITS_ASLY
RETAIL_ASLY
COST_ASLY
UNITS_ASREGLY
RETAIL_ASREGLY
UNITS_ASMKDLY
RETAIL_ASMKDLY
UNITS_AS_PLN
RETAIL_AS_PLN

Comment: ACT_SLS_0 tables has following columns : ASP
GA
PMM_STYLEID
COLORCODE
SIZECODE
STORENUM
WEEK
UNITS_ASLY
RETAIL_ASLY
COST_ASLY
UNITS_ASREGLY
RETAIL_ASREGLY
UNITS_ASMKDLY
RETAIL_ASMKDLY
UNITS_AS_PLN
RETAIL_AS_PLN

Comment: Error - Invalid Identifier is due two GA columns created in src table after using joins. Now How can I get single GA from src table

Comment: by selecting the individual columns that you want to display from t1 and t2, rather than doing `select *`